# Improving counting of word frequencies with hashmap

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, count, hashmap

For one of my applications, the following function has to be called very often. This function takes up a lot of CPU and hence I am wondering if you know how to improve the performance.

The code counts the occurrences of a combination of four characters. During testing, I found that the number of entries in the map are around 100. The length of *text* is in the range of 100 to 800. The initial size of 200 is a guess and the code seems to run faster than without specifying an initial size. It is probably not the optimal value, though.

```
private Map<String, Integer> getTetagramCount(final String text) {
    final Map<String, Integer> cipherTetagrams = new HashMap<String, Integer>(200);

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - 4; i++) {
        final String tet = text.substring(i, i + 4);

        final Integer count = cipherTetagrams.get(tet);
        if (count != null) {
            cipherTetagrams.put(tet, count + 1);
        } else {
            cipherTetagrams.put(tet, 1);
        }
    }

    return cipherTetagrams;
}
```

Comment: Do you know the exhaustive range of the characters in text? (e.g. they're all lower-case letters between 'a' and 'z')

Comment: Yes, the range is all upper case letters and the numbers 0 to 9.

Comment: if that's the case, I think something like my answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do a lot of work in NLP and machine learning, so I have to do this sort of thing all the time, and there are a ***ton*** of opportunities for optimization.

A few points to consider:

1. First of all, you're getting killed by the standard JDK HashMap class. It's a nice container for general-purpose computing, but it's terrible for high-performance computing. For each entry into your collection (a four-character string (8 bytes) and an integer (4 bytes), the standard java HashMap will consume:

   - A string object

     - 8-byte object overhead
     - 4-byte reference to an array
     - 4-byte string-length field
   - A character array

     - 8-byte object overhead
     - 2-bytes for each character (times 4 characters) = 8 bytes
     - 4-byte array-length field
   - An Integer object

     - 8-byte object overhead
     - 4-byte int value
   - A HashMap.Entry object

     - 8-byte object overhead
     - 4-byte Key reference
     - 4-byte Value reference

   So your tiny little 12 bytes of data becomes 64 bytes. And that's before the HashMap has allocated an array of hash values to use during its lookup operations. Keep in mind that all those tiny little objects mean more work for the GC, but more importantly, it means that your objects span a larger swath of main memory and are less likely to fit within the CPU cache. When you have lots of cache misses, you lose performance.

   *NOTE: A commenter reminded me that all the substrings will share the same underlying character array, which is a good point that I'd forgotten about. But still, that means each map entry goes from being 64 bytes down to 44 bytes. Which is still a shame, when there should only be 12 bytes.*
2. Boxing and unboxing all those integer values causes your code to run more slowly and to consume more memory. In most cases, we don't really care about that, and the vanilla HashMap implementation is fine, even with its mandatory boxing and greedy memory consumption. But in your case, if this code is run within a tight inner loop, we'd rather have a specialized class that knows its values will always be integers and eliminates the need for boxing.
3. If you dig down into the JDK source code, you'll see that your code will end up invoking string's `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods twice. Once for the `map.get()` and once for the `map.put()`. But there's a different kind of collection called a ***HashBag*** that can perform lookup, insertion, and count incrementation with only one lookup. A "bag" collection is kind of like a "set", except that it can contain duplicates, and it keeps track of how many duplicates there are. For each of your tetragrams, you'd just call `bag.put(tetragram)` without having to first retrieve and update a count. Unfortunately, there are no bag implementations in the JDK, so you'll need to find one elsewhere, or write one yourself.
4. Luckily, your tetragrams can be losslessly encoded as `long` values (since each java character is 2 bytes wide, and a `long` gives you eight bytes to work with). You can therefore iterate through the character array and convert each tetragram to a `long`, and avoid all the overhead of constructing so many tiny strings. Then, you can keep your results in a `LongIntHashMap` (from the Trove library). This will be *much* faster than your current implementation, because you can avoid creating all those tiny little string objects.
5. Although the Trove `LongIntHashMap` is quite excellent, it isn't quite as good as a `LongHashBag` would be. There's no `equals` invocation (since longs can be compared with the == operator), but you'll still pay the price of two `hashCode` invocations. If you want to get really aggressive with optimization, you could look at the source code of the `LongIntHashMap` and figure out how to modify it into a `LongHashBag`. It's not that difficult, and ultimately, that's exactly what I've done in my own code.

---

### Update 1:

Okay, here's a little bit of code:

```
private LongHashBag countTetragrams(String text) {

  // Homework assignment: find a good LongHashBag implementation, or
  // grab the LongIntHashMap implementation from Trove, and tweak it
  // to work as a Bag
  LongHashBag bag = new LongHashBag(500);

  // There are no tetragrams in this string.
  if (text.length() < 4) return bag;

  // Shortcut: if we calculate the first tetragram before entering
  // the loop, then we can use bit-shifting logic within the loop
  // to create all subsequent tetragram values.
  char[] c = text.toCharArray();
  long tetragram = ((long) c[0] << 48) |
     (((long) c[1]) << 32) |
     (((long) c[2]) << 16) |
     ((long) c[3]);

  bag.add(tetragram);

  for (int i = 4, last = text.length(); i < last; i++) {
     // During each loop iteration, the leftmost 2-bytes are shifted
     // out of the tetragram, to make room for the 2-bytes from the
     // current character.
     tetragram = (tetragram << 16) | ((long) c[i]);
     bag.add(tetragram);
  }

  return bag;
}
```

---

### Update 2:

I just did some testing of various solutions, and I was about to get about a 25% performance improvement using the `LongHashBag` approach instead of the standard `HashMap` approach.

However, I was about to get a 300% improvement by recycling the resultant objects. Basically, instead of doing this:

```
private LongHashBag countTetragrams(String text) {

  // Creates a new HashBag on every invocation. Very wasteful.
  LongHashBag bag = new LongHashBag(500);

  // ...blah blah blah...

  return bag;
}
```

...I'm now doing this...

```
private void countTetragrams(String text, LongHashBag bag) {

  // Return the object to a neutral state, and recycle it.
  bag.clear()

  // ...blah blah blah...
}
```

The calling code is responsible for creating the LongHashBag object and ensuring that we're done with it by the time we call the count method again.

But it would also work to do this...

```
private LongHashBag countTetragrams(String text) {

  // Return the object to a neutral state, and recycle it.
  LongHashBag bag = retrieveLongHashBagFromObjectPool();

  // ...blah blah blah...
  return bag;
}
```

... which will add a little bit of overhead for maintaining the pool. And the calling code would have to remember to put the bag back into the pool when it finishes using it. But the performance benefits could definitely be worth it.

Incidentally, these are exactly the kinds of tricks I use every day. Object pooling has become one of my most reliable tricks for improving performance.

But like I said, recycling those objects yields a 300% performance improvement.

Comment: The character array is shared over all string instances in this case.  The boxing will probably be slower but won't consume more memory; most of the values are cached on a modern VM and they exceed the cache the cache size can be tuned...Now to read the rest!

Comment: `hashCode()` is cached for String but the point about `equals()` being called twice is a good one.

Comment: I think this is the best answer if you can't make guarantees about the contents of the characters.  In that case, you will basically need to resort to a hash table or some other sparse data type.

Comment: Turns out the OP *can* make guarantees about the data.

Answer (score 7):

You might try implementing a [prefix tree (trie)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_tree) as a data structure, particularly if you know the range of the characters.  It would be at most 4 levels deep, giving you potentially constant (and faster constant) time.  How this will perform compared to the hashmap really depends on the data you have.

**Edit**

Alternatively, again if you know the range of the characters, you could just stuff them into a much faster data type.

Since you know all of your characters are between A and Z or 0 and 9, you can compact that into 6 bits each:

```
 public int index(String str, int startPos) {
     return 
    ((str.charAt(startPos+3) - '0') << 18) + 
    ((str.charAt(startPos+2) - '0') << 12) + 
    ((str.charAt(startPos+1) - '0') << 6) + 
     (str.charAt(startPos) - '0');
 }

 //...    
 int[] counts = new int[42*42*42*42];
 final int max = text.length() - 4;
 for ( int i = 0; i < max; i++ ) {
     counts[index(text, i)]++;
 }
```

**Edit**: updated the example above to cover `A-Z, 0-9`.  Now note two things:  First, you have to create a big array, but you don't need to do that every time (you do have to clear it every time though!).  Second, this provides really fast lookup of the number of occurrences of a certain word, but if you want to iterate over all the words (say to find all words that actually occurred), that takes `O(42^4)` time.

Comment: Also regarding my edit, you could also use a smaller data type if you wished (byte/short).  Can't guarantee it'd be faster, but it should pack to less memory.

Comment: +1, this could even be done with a multidimensional array pretty effectively. Also, there's no real reason that you need the `index` function and it could add a small (but unnecessary) amount of overhead.

Comment: @Mark: I doubt the indexing would *add* overhead (since it eliminates 3 out of the 4 bounds checks that have to be done) but using a multi-dimensional array is certainly simpler to comprehend.  I guess technically by using multi-dimensional arrays though, you would be creating `1+26^3` arrays instead of 1.  Depending on how the JRE handles that internally, that could be a big hit.

Comment: The indexing wouldn't add overhead, putting the math in a function does.

Comment: @Mark: Should be inlined by HotSpot after a run or two, no?  If not, you could always just inline it manually.

Comment: I'm suggesting to inline it manually, I'm not entirely familiar with what the Java optimizer does in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Well, one potential option is to change from using an *immutable* wrapper type to a mutable one:

```
public final class Counter
{
    private int value;

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void increment()
    {
        value++;
    }
}
```

Then change your code to:

```
private Map<String, Counter> getTetagramCount(final String text) {
    final Map<String, Counter> cipherTetagrams = new HashMap<String, Counter>(200);

    // Micro-optimization (may well not help) - only take the
    // length and subtract 4 once
    int lastStart = text.length() - 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastStart; i++) {
        final String tet = text.substring(i, i + 4);

        Counter counter = cipherTetagrams.get(tet);
        if (counter == null) {
            counter = new Counter();
            cipherTetagrams.put(tet, counter);
        }
        counter.increment();
    }

    return cipherTetagrams;
}
```

That way you only ever "put" a value associated with a word once... after that you increment it in-place.

(You could potentially use `AtomicInteger` instead of `Counter` if you wanted to use a built-in type.)

Comment: Jon, can you please comment on what I said?  Getting an upvote or even comment from you would make my Friday :)

Comment: If only one thread is executing the increments your Counter implementation is best.  Why is this being downvoted?

Comment: +1 @Jon Skeet, I think you should take some time to explain why this is faster as it may not be immediately obvious to everyone that avoiding the unneeded "put" call helps to remove some wasted CPU cycles in rehashing a Key (I think String caches the hash though) and finding the same Value bucket that was literally just found.

Comment: @Tim: I think it's more avoiding object creation.  Although likely all of the integers used here would be pulled from `Integer`'s cache.

Answer (score 1):

Big-O optimization aside (if there are any), there is a very simple way to greatly speedup your application: use something than the default Java APIs, which are **very** slow when it comes to dealing with a *lot* of data.

Replace:

```
Map<String, Counter>
```

With Trove's (which means you have to add the Trove jar to your project):

```
TObjectIntHashMap<String>
```

And:

```
final Integer count = cipherTetagrams.get(tet);
```

with:

```
final int count = cipherTetagrams.get(tet);
```

Because when you work with a *lot* of data, using wrappers like Integer instead of primitives (like int) and using the default Java API is the surest way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Commenting on my answer: there was an article recently about doing high-performance computing using Java and the summary was basically: *"It is possible as long as you don't use the default Java APIs"*.  And, yup, I do crunch numbers using Java and, no, I don't use the default Java APIs nor the garbage-generating wrapper classes ;)

Comment: Note that in addition to not using the wrapper classes, Trove's HashMap are simply better implemented: way less garbage is generated upon resizing etc. (hash map resizing are *much* faster under Trove).

Comment: Except, in the posted code, it is unlikely that the hashmap used is ever resized since the initial capacity is set so high.

Comment: @Tim Bender: but certainly it doesn't change the fact that Trove's hash map resize much faster, which may still be of interest to the OP.  Note that this wasn't in my answer but in a comment and the fact still holds.

Comment: yes, I was only commenting on the comment and I didn't vote on your answer at all. It would be nice to see some actual benchmarks for some common applications. I'm definitely interested to see whether or not this enhancement is faster than @Jon Skeet's

Answer (score -1):

I haven't even begun to analyze your code and I noticed that this method does not operate on any member fields and can be made static.  Static methods will always perform better than non-static methods.  I'll look for more issues in a minute...

Comment: There are only two reasons I can see why a static method would perform better: 1) it could be inlined (irrelevant here); 2) there's no need to check the target reference for nullity. While the second point is true, I *highly* doubt that it will be significant in the slightest, compared with all the substrings etc being taken within the method.

Comment: @Amir: If your method isn't *using* any instance members it's probably not going to be much of a performance gain to make it static.  But it's better style anyway IMO.

Comment: OK - but what about the cost of doing the dynamic dispatch off of the object guys?

Comment: @Amir: presumably the high cost is incurred *within* the method, not just by the sheer number of times the method is called.  This isn't recursive so I can't see it making a non-trivial difference.

Comment: I don't get people doing their sweeping downvotes.  There's nothing stricly wrong about this answer, and the method probably should be static anyway for style if nothing else.  It won't make a noticable difference, but that doesn't make it incorrect information.  Upvote to counter.

Comment: There is something wrong with this answer, its useless. but if you can provide benchmark and prove that making it static really change anything(you can even make arguments and class final(with private constructor))

Comment: Whats useless about my answer?  Did you read Jon or Mark's comments?   There is absolutely no reason to think that declaring the class final or the method arguments final will affect performance.  Declaring the method static on the other hand, *can* have an affect on performance.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this would be faster, but I have a feeling it would be.

```
private Map<String, Integer> getTetagramCount( final String text) {

    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for( int i =0; i < text.length() - 4; i++) {
        list.add( text.substring( i, i+4);
    }

    Collections.sort( list);

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>( list.size());
    String last = null;
    int count = 0;
    for( String tetagram : list) {
        if( tetagram != last && last != null) {
            map.put( tetagram, count);
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
        last = tetagram;
    }
    if( tetagram != null) {
        map.put( tetagram, count);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Depending on what you are doing with the Map when you are done, you may not need the conversion to a Map at the end.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken I do believe the author's original algorithm is O(N).

Comment: You are right.  I was thinking Hash Table insertion was O(log N), but it is O(1).  However, because The collection is only a few hundred large, my algorithm may still perform better for small N.